# PHP framework Symfony with WAMPP/XAMPP

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony1

I've decided that it's time to learn some PHP framework and I make my choice for Symfony.But there is a problem - I use WAMPP on one of my PCs and on the other I'm with XAMPP and I'm having problem setting up Symfony.I try to follow the tutorial, but it just doesn't work.So I'm wondering - is there any information that I couldn't find and where it's explained how to install Symfony on Windows XP SP3 with WAMPP, or maybe it's better to remove WAMPP and to make some efforts and try to set up all the programs manually, maybe I should start with something more simple as first framework...I just don't know.Will appreciate any advice given.
  Thank you
-Leron

Comment: What version of Symfony? Can you link the tutorial that you're using please?

Comment: I'm trying to install Symfony v.1.4.11.I'm following the offical guide on symfony homepage as well the information given on this page - http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToInstallSymfonyOnWindowsWithWamp

Comment: i've been using xampp for years and symfony or zend framework work perfectly, what's your issue? have you run the script `php check_configuration.php` from symfony to check your environment? is php in your environment path? give us more info :D

Comment: In cmd when i try to install PEAR under WAMMP it throws an error, so I made a second install of PHP alone and make everything as said, but then when I run symfony it won't install at all.

Comment: To black sensei : I ran check_configuration.php and the only problem was with PEAR.Maybe this is it.It doesn't allow me to install it using WAMPP's PHP installation, is there any trick to do this.And yes I added PHP to my execute path.

Answer (score 0):

This might help and or give you some pointers. OK its MAMP on OSX which is not quite your question but it will give you various pointers and it is in the same area so you can check out.

[Adam Stacey's blog](http://www.adamstacey.co.uk/category/symfony/)